# Django deploy collectstatic error

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv

I'm trying to deploy my Python Django project on server (useing Nginx). 
But when I collect statics

```
python manage.py collectstatics
```

I get the next error:

> Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
>   ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

But I have Django and "turned on" virtualenv

pip freeze:

```
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.4
command-not-found==0.3
Django==1.10.7
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-ckeditor==5.3.0
django-haystack==2.6.1
django-imagekit==4.0.1
django-js-asset==0.1.1
django-material==1.0.0
django-parler==1.8
flickrapi==2.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.5
language-selector==0.1
oauthlib==2.0.2
olefile==0.44
pilkit==2.0
Pillow==4.2.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.20.0
python-apt==1.1.0b1
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.1
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
requirements==0.1
six==1.10.0
solid-i18n==1.4.1
ssh-import-id==5.5
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.21.1
virtualenv==15.0.1
Whoosh==2.7.4
```

Comment: after you do `workon` show your `pip freeze`, please

Comment: Do you have Django installed outside of virtualenv?

Comment: @BearBrown, I added it into my question

Comment: @phd, yes, I have

Comment: you install `virtualenv` inside `virtualenv` ? looks like you show `pip freeze` of your system, but not virtualenv

Comment: @BearBrown, the same pip freeze list I have at my system too..

Comment: and you install `virtualenv` inside `virtualenv` ?

Comment: @BearBrown, I didn't do it but ran requirements.txt of project. Maybe this could have affected that

Comment: `virtualenv` intended to separate globally installed packages from local. If you have Django installed outside of virtualenv but not inside then Django is not available inside. You have to install Django and all other required packages **after** activating virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you `static` path in nginx configuration file.

```
location /static/ {
        alias   <static directory path>;
    }
```

It should be same as setting.py `SETTING_ROOT` path

```
STATIC_ROOT = '<static directory path>'
```

Comment: I try to configure Nginx at first time. You mean nginx.conf file? In it I have no such path because there is no "location {}"

Comment: yes, nginx.conf file. 
server {   
    ...
    location /static {    
        autoindex on; 
    }
}